# GWT - Set FlexTable font-size dynamically?

Tags: css, gwt, font-size, flextable

I'm working on a GWT project where the font-sizes need to be set dynamically. I'm attempting to use

```
myFlexTable.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontSize", Integer.toString(font_size) + "px");
```

to set the font-size of the text in `myFlexTable`. Unfortunately, this setting is being overwritten by a 13px font-size that I don't know how to fix. When using the above code on a GWT label or input, it correctly sets the font-size. When searching for a solution I've only been able to find solutions which are edits of the static CSS. Any suggestions as to how I might fix this? Thank you much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may also simply be that you're setting the font size of the entire table, and not individual elements. Try checking the classes and CSS of your flextable in production mode via Inspect element of Firebug or such.

**UPDATE:** Edited post to contain only the correct solution.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Any idea what the style name being used might be right off hand? If not, I'm sure I'll find it soon enough.

Comment: For any following behind me, I ended up setting the CELL font-size for each cell using: 
myFlexTable.getCellFormatter().getElement(i, j).getStyle().setProperty("fontSize", Integer.toString(font_size) + "px");

Answer (score 0):

You can apply new css at run time for `flextable`.

```
myflexTable.removeStyle("old_style");
myflexTable.setStyle("new_style");
```

Comment: But this is still just applying a static CSS dynamically, right? I can't change the actual value in the CSS this way? Or can I first create the style dynamically then apply it this way?